# Using langChain's VectorDBQAChain or ConversationalRetrievalQAChain, why would OpenAI return 'I don't know?

Tags: langchain

When using langChain's VectorDBQAChain or ConversationalRetrievalQAChain to query Pinecone with contextual records, and then asking a new question that is unrelated to the existing context, OpenAI will respond with 'I don't know.

```js
Response：{
  "text": "I don't know.",
  "sourceDocuments": [
    {
      "pageContent": "Hi! I'm Jim.",
      "metadata": {
        "role": "User",
        "window_id": "01234567890"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
import initClient from "/var/task/initClient.mjs";
import VectorStoreUpdater from "/var/task/updateVectorStore.mjs";
import { VectorDBQAChain } from "langchain/chains";
import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from "langchain/embeddings/openai";
import { PineconeStore } from "langchain/vectorstores/pinecone";

export const handler = async ({ window_id = "01234567890", query = "How many steps are there to put an elephant into a refrigerator?" }) => {
   const { model, pinecone, pineconeIndex } = await initClient();
   const vectorStore = await PineconeStore.fromExistingIndex(
      new OpenAIEmbeddings(),
      {
         pineconeIndex,
         filter: { window_id },
      }
   );

   const chain = VectorDBQAChain.fromLLM(model, vectorStore, {
      returnSourceDocuments: true,
   });

   const response = await chain.call({ query });
   return response
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there are prompt preset by Langchain when invoke openai api:

> Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end.
> If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try
> to make up an answer.\n\n.....

You would view the debug message by enable verbose flag of the input model
`new OpenAI({ verbose: true });`